# Disable past dates using texbox Asp.Net C#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I am working on an Asp.Net C# web app pulling data from from SQL Server. I am using a textbox with properties set as date for uses to select a date, I need a method or code that will disable the user from selecting a past day from the present?

Or alternatively when the user selects a date and clicks save the database must give an error for the user to select a future date and not accept what has been saved.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: The best help I can give at this stage is that you should have a go first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, having a textbox will only hold the date value, your validation logic, which is not allowing past date to be saved, should be implemented at possibly form submit event or textbox mouse click out event. It could be like

```
DateTime inputDateTime = convert.ToDateTIme(TextBox1.Value); 
if (inputDateTime<DateTime.Now) 
{ 
  Throw Exceptoin("you have entered the wrong value");
}
 else 
{ 
  save...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set from jquery.

`jQuery(function ($) {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        showOtherMonths: true,
        selectOtherMonths: false,
   });
  });`

This code will help you to do not select previous dates.

Answer (score 2):

Thank You @jeffrey using the sample code you supplied I was able to come up with a working solution below.

```
protected void Btn_Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime inputDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox1.Text);
        if (inputDateTime < DateTime.Now)
        {
            Error.Text=("You Cannot Save A Past Date");
        }
        else
        {
            period cv = new period();
            cv.PeriodStart = Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox1.Text);
            cv.CreateAgent = Convert.ToString(SessionName.Text);
            cv.CreateDate = DateTime.Now;
            ZS_CS_EVO_IntegrationEntities db = new ZS_CS_EVO_IntegrationEntities();
            db.periods.Add(cv);
            db.SaveChanges();
            Error.Text = ("Date Saved Successfully");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to compare your textbox's data using [DateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx) and just admit values that are equal or higher than it. That way you prevent unwelcomed values, as you restrict them.